# Login with Linkedin SDK iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, linkedin-api

I have implemented linkedin-sdk for login process. Created key on developer account. Following is the code:

```
    [LISDKSessionManager createSessionWithAuth:permissions state:nil showGoToAppStoreDialog:YES successBlock:^(NSString *returnState){
            NSLog(@"%s","success called!");
            LISDKSession *session = [[LISDKSessionManager sharedInstance] session];
            NSLog(@"Session  : %@", session.description);
            }];
        } errorBlock:^(NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"Error called  : %@", error);
        }];


func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any]) -> Bool {

 print("url..",url)

if LISDKCallbackHandler.application(app, open: url, sourceApplication: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as! String?, annotation: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.annotation]) {
            return true
        }
}
```

url... li4366914://error?state=(null)&info=INVALID_APP_ID&domain=LISDKInvalidRequestError&description=Invalid%20Application%20ID

It goes to Linkedin app[image: Linkedin authentication] but when it comes back to app, showing invalid session. Unable to find the reason. Wasted number of hours. Help me if someone has understanding about this error.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you add a screenshot, or the exact wording of the invalid session error? Is it throwing an exception or is it calling the error callback?

Comment: what are the permissions you given

Comment: it will occur in many scenario's. plz add some additional info for track.

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik Please check updated question

Comment: @joelliusp Please check updated question

Answer (score 4):

The LinkedIn SDK has been deprecated.

> The Mobile SDK is not currently supported. [Learn more](https://engineering.linkedin.com/blog/2018/12/developer-program-updates)
>
> <sub>Ref: https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/ios-sdk</sub>

"Learn more" takes you to LinkedIn's [Developer Program Updates](https://engineering.linkedin.com/blog/2018/12/developer-program-updates) which states:

> Changes to the program include:
>
> - APIs: Developers must migrate their apps to our new APIs.
>
>   - Sign In with LinkedIn: Sign In with LinkedIn enables members to choose a more convenient way to log-in to third party apps and allows those apps to learn more about their new user. This API will only recognize a new “Lite Profile” permission, which supports a reduced set of member profile fields. See the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/sign-in-with-linkedin?context=linkedin/consumer/context) for more details.
>
> ...
>
> - Authentication, SDKs, and Plugins: We are also deprecating several obsolete or seldomly-used products and technologies.
>
>   - Authentication: We will sunset OAuth 1.0 and require all developers to use OAuth 2.0, which we have supported since 2013. OAuth 2.0 is the industry standard and widely-used by the majority of people building on our platform.
>   - **SDKs: Our JavaScript and Mobile Software Development Kits (SDKs) will stop working. Developers will need to migrate to using OAuth 2.0 directly from their apps.**
>
> ...
>
> **To reiterate: all developers need to migrate their apps to our newest APIs and OAuth 2.0 by March 1, 2019.** To help navigate the migration process, please see the [technical migration guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/migration-faq?context=linkedin/consumer/context) on the LinkedIn section of the Microsoft Docs website.
>
> <sub>Ref: https://engineering.linkedin.com/blog/2018/12/developer-program-updates</sub>

---

### Summary:

The SDK is old and not maintained anymore. It must be using older APIs which have been dropped and I guess that's why even if you set up your project properly, the SDK simply won't work as expected.

#### Options:

- Follow their [documentation on implementing v2 directly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/sign-in-with-linkedin?context=linkedin/consumer/context)
- Follow their [technical migration guide from v1 to v2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/migration-faq?context=linkedin/consumer/context)

Comment: Yes, I already go through it. Is this the only way to fix the issue?

Comment: @MinkleGarg Not sure if this is the **only** way to fix the issue but it's clearly mentioned you **need** to migrate. If not today then tomorrow. What's the point fixing the issue now only to reimplement it a month or 2 later? Do it right this time itself. Check their [FAQ](https://developer.linkedin.com/support/faq) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

By reading your log, it says that there is a problem with the APPID

> //url... li4366914://error?state=(null)&info=INVALID_APP_ID&domain=LISDKInvalidRequestError&description=Invalid%20Application%20ID

You should confirm that application bundle identifier should be same on the developer portal of LinkedIn and in your application.

You can confirm once [here](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/ios-sdk#)

Comment: No, from your question it is logging, print("url..",url), which is //url... li4366914://error?state=(null)&info=INVALID_APP_ID.....

Comment: @MinkleGarg , this is correct, check the info and description of the error. There is problem in App ID. Check if it is correct in url schemes.